# Input Form On Left And Right Side Of Page

Tags: html, css

What im trying to do is to make the page has two sections, on the left and right side. But, i only managed to get it working on the left side.

I tried to search on internet but found nothing and im new to css. For example radio button positioned on the right side while the input form is on the left size. So in that way, i can utilize the webpage area.

```css
 .myForm {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 100em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: none;
    }

 #left{
     width: 60%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #right{
     width: 40%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        padding: 0 0 0 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .myForm * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .myForm fieldset {
    border: none;
 width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .myForm legend,
    .myForm label {
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .myForm label.choice {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

    .myForm label {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    }
 
 .myForm label_child {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    }

    .myForm input[type="text"],
    .myForm input[type="tel"],
    .myForm input[type="datetime-local"],
    .myForm select,
    .myForm textarea {
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    }



    .myForm input[type="radio"],
    .myForm input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: 40%;
    }

    .myForm button {
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background: #eee;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 90%;
    margin-top: 1.8em;
    }

    .myForm button:hover {
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
 
 .body{
 width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form class="myForm">

<div id="left">
    <p>
    <label>Project Name
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" required>
    </label> 
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Project ID 
    <input type="tel" name="phone_number">
    </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Project Delivery
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Development</option>
        <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Project Status
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
        <option value="c_p">close</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Country
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Region
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Pen.Malaysia</option>
        <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Block
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Tangga Barat Cluster Gas Field</option>
        <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Field
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Tangga</option>
        <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>PCSB Equity
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="100 %"required>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Currency
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">MYR</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Contract Category
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">N/A</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </p>


    <p>
    <label>Project Start Date
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>Project End Date
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>
   </div>  
    <fieldset id="right">
    <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="baby"> Only Applicable To JV Module</label></p>
    <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="wheelchair"> Use Project Assurance Plan </label></p>
    <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="tip" checked> Display In EPMS Dashboards And Reports </label></p>
    <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="tip"> Display In Performance Daashboard </label></p>
    </fieldset>
 
 <fieldset id="right">
 <p>
  <label>PPP
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
  <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
      </select>
</label>
    </p>
 </fieldset id="right">
 
   <p>
    <label>Date:
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>
 
  <fieldset id="right">
 <p>
  <label>Milestone
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
  <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
      </select>
</label>
    </p>
 </fieldset id="right">
 
   <p>
    <label>Date:
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>
 
  <fieldset id="right">
 <p>
  <label>Production
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
  <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
      </select>
</label>
    </p>
 </fieldset id="right">
 
   <p>
    <label>Date:
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>
 
  <fieldset id="right">
 <p>
  <label>Cost
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
  <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
      </select>
</label>
    </p>
 </fieldset id="right">
 
   <p>
    <label>Date:
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>

 <fieldset id="right">
 <p>
  <label>Manpower:
    <select name="workflow" >
        <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
  <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
      </select>
</label>
    </p>
 </fieldset id="right">
 
   <p>
    <label>Date:
    <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p><button>Submit Project</button></p>  <p><button>Cancel</button></p>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Im trying to do like in this picture
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Layout

I added a CSS class `.width-6`. By placing this class on the container of each 'half' of the elements you want to split should allow you to achieve the desired result.

Note, I named it `width-6` because the conventions in most modern CSS frameworks is to use a [12 column grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

#### Unique id attributes

I also took the liberty of removing unnecessary and invalid `id`s *("right", "left")* in your code. These `id`s must be unique per HTML document and be the same logic you should almost never use them for layout styling. The layout you intended is most commonly implemented with a standardized & reusable grid system based on `classe`s.

[id Global Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: block;
}

.width-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.container-padding {
  padding: 3em 15%;
}

.myForm {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 100em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: none;
}

.myForm fieldset {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.myForm legend,
.myForm label {
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.myForm label.choice {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.myForm label {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.myForm label_child {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.myForm input[type="text"],
.myForm input[type="tel"],
.myForm input[type="datetime-local"],
.myForm select,
.myForm textarea {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.myForm input[type="radio"],
.myForm input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.myForm button {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-top: 1.8em;
}

.myForm button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form class="myForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="width-6 container-padding">
        <p>
          <label>Project Name
            <input type="text" name="customer_name" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Project ID
            <input type="tel" name="phone_number">
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Project Delivery
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">Development</option>
              <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Project Status
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
              <option value="c_p">close</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Country
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">Malaysia</option>
              <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Region
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">Pen.Malaysia</option>
              <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Block
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">Tangga Barat Cluster Gas Field</option>
              <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Field
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">Tangga</option>
              <option value="c_p">Time-Phase Open Budget</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>PCSB Equity
            <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="100 %" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Currency
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">MYR</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Contract Category
            <select name="workflow">
              <option value="dummy data">N/A</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>


        <p>
          <label>Project Start Date
            <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Project End Date
            <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="width-6 container-padding">
        <fieldset>
          <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="baby"> Only Applicable To JV
              Module</label></p>
          <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="wheelchair"> Use Project Assurance
              Plan </label></p>
          <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="tip" checked> Display In EPMS
              Dashboards And Reports </label></p>
          <p><label class="choice"> <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="tip"> Display In Performance
              Daashboard </label></p>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>PPP
              <select name="workflow">
                <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
                <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </p>
        </fieldset>

        <p>
          <label>Date:
            <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>Milestone
              <select name="workflow">
                <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
                <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </p>
        </fieldset>

        <p>
          <label>Date:
            <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>Production
              <select name="workflow">
                <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
                <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </p>
        </fieldset>

        <p>
          <label>Date:
            <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>Cost
              <select name="workflow">
                <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
                <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </p>
        </fieldset>

        <p>
          <label>Date:
            <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
          </label>
        </p>

        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>Manpower:
              <select name="workflow">
                <option value="dummy data">Open</option>
                <option value="dummy data">Close</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>Date:
              <input type="datetime-local" name="pickup_time" required>
            </label>
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="width-6 container-padding">
        <p><button>Submit Project</button></p>
        <p><button>Cancel</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[Foundation: The Grid](https://foundation.zurb.com/grid.html)
[Bootstrap: Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Once you have the basics of CSS down I'd highly recommend looking into one of these front-end frameworks to help eliminate much of the repetitive style & layout formatting, while helping normalize issues between different browsers and device types.

Comment: i've updated the code, would u mind looking at it again?

Comment: Ok I think it should be what you want now, but you should be to adjust the basic layout from here.

Answer (score 0):

I placed all the the `input fields` in left ID and and `check-boxes fieldset` in right ID.
Please check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1HAOEYH66XV)

Comment: It works, but seems like i need to adjust the box border to make the radio button exactly on the right side.

Comment: would u mind to take a look again for my updated code?

Comment: Please check this:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1HFXKUGHULF